# React native QR scanner to webview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I converted my app from expo to bare react native. I had a barcode/QR scanner that was working great with the expo module "Expo-bar-code-scanner" I tried to convert from expo bar code scanner to React native qr scanner but I've been running into problems and not sure how to fix. What is expected is to scan a qr code containing a URL and have that opened in a webview. What is happening however since converting is webview failing to open and my overlay is failing to display.

Please help... Thank you :)

Below is my QRscreen.js. URL's are omitted

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Modal, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
  import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
  import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';
  import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

  export default function App(){
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(true);
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
    const [uri, setUri] = useState('omitted');


useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const { status } = await QRCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
    setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
  })();
}, []);

const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
  setScanned(true);
  setModalVisible(true);
    // console.warn("Scan returned " + data);
    setUri({ uri: data })
};



if (hasPermission === false) {
  return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
}

return (
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column'
    }}>
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      visible={modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        setScanned(false);
      }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          source={{uri: uri['uri']}}
        />

        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{
            backgroundColor:'black',
            padding: 15,
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            setScanned(false);
          }}
          underlayColor='slategray'
        >
          <Text style={{ color:'white', fontSize: 15 }}>Re Scan</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </Modal>

    <QRCodeScanner
      onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 100 }}>
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 5 }}>
          <Image
            style={{
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              marginBottom: 20,
            }}
            source={{ uri: 'omitted' }}
          />
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingBottom: 10}}>
            QR Code Reader
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderTopWidth: 5,
            borderBottomWidth: 5,
            borderLeftWidth: 1,
            borderRightWidth: 1,
            paddingVertical: 80,
            paddingHorizontal: 100,
          }}
        />

        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 5 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15}}>
            QR Scan...
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </QRCodeScanner>
    </View>
);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the not expected output is using **onBarCodeScanned** method to listen the event on scanning success, but as per requirements I can see you are scanning **QRCode** not **BarCode**.

Have a try by using below example:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';

export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
  const [uri, setUri] = useState('omitted');

  //   useEffect(() => {
  //     (async () => {
  //       const {status} = await QRCodeScanner?.requestPermissionsAsync();
  //       setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
  //     })();
  //   }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({type, data}) => {
    ref.current?._setScanning(true);
    setModalVisible(true);
    // console.warn("Scan returned " + data);
    setUri({uri: data});
  };

  const ref = useRef();

  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
      }}>
      <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={false} visible={modalVisible}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <WebView style={{flex: 1}} source={{uri: uri.uri}} />

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              padding: 15,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              //   ref.current?._setScanning(true);
              ref.current?._setScanning(false);
              setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            }}
            underlayColor="slategray">
            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 15}}>Re Scan</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <QRCodeScanner
        // onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
        onRead={handleBarCodeScanned}
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View style={{marginBottom: 100}}>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 5}}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                resizeMode: 'contain',
                marginBottom: 20,
              }}
              source={{uri: 'omitted'}}
            />
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                paddingBottom: 10,
              }}>
              QR Code Reader
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              borderColor: 'white',
              borderTopWidth: 5,
              borderBottomWidth: 5,
              borderLeftWidth: 1,
              borderRightWidth: 1,
              paddingVertical: 80,
              paddingHorizontal: 100,
            }}
          />

          <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 5}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 15}}>QR Scan...</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </QRCodeScanner>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are Setting the Uri state incorrectly as `uri` is string by inference provided as "omitted" so how could it will accept `{}`.

So change

> setUri({ uri: data })

to

> setUri(data)

assuming you are confirmed that data is a string. Check this by logging it before setting to the `setUri`.

And also change

> source={{uri: uri['uri']}}

with

> source={{uri}}

as uri is obliviously not an array.